# Native Qubit-Qubit-Resonator Interaction

Tags: circuit-qed

Recently I've been working on a setup with two qubits and a resonator. And usually people consider the following scenarios:

- Qubit-Qubit Interaction something like $\hat{\sigma}_X^{(a)}\hat{\sigma}_X^{(b)}$
- Qubit-Resonator Interaction something like $\hat{\sigma}_X^{(a)}(\hat{a} +\hat{a}^\dagger)$

And combinations of them present in the same setup.

My question is about a native Qubit-Qubit-Resonator interaction term like $\hat{\sigma}_X^{(a)}\hat{\sigma}_X^{(b)}(\hat{a} +\hat{a}^\dagger)$. Is there a native way to setup such an interaction? Or any other way to set it up?